# How to place elements below each other in FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I am using `FrameLayout` in my Layout and button displays over first `LinearLayout`. I want to display this button under first `LinearLayout` and not to change `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. Is it possible? Haven't found any solution, only to change `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

This is how it looks now: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6ZgX.png)

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@id/menu_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@style/LeftDrawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/menu_user_profile"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    style="@style/MenuTopBox">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1.0">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/menu_avatar"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_default_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_default_size"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_default_avatar"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/menu_avatar_photo"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_camera"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/menu_avatar"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@id/menu_profile"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_margin_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_micro"
            android:text="@string/menu_profile"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            style="@style/TextBig" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@id/menu_logout_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/menu_logout_button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_menu_logout"
        style="@style/ButtonMenu" />
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your layout contains **a lot**  of nested views, this may cause your layout to be slower and do more calculation than it needs to.

I can recommend using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).

**But why** - It's a simple layout that meant to optimize and flatten the view hierarchy of your layouts (meaning without nested views) causing faster loading time of your layout.

Also, constraintLayout will **save you a lot of time** because making your layout with it is really easy and simple.

Here is an example of a layout that looks like you want to using constraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="camera"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button4" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: have you actually benchmarked it? Just today I had to replace a ConstraintLayout with multiple layouts because it was slower than multiple layouts.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Interesting, could you elaborate? you replace constraintLayout with what other layouts? and any chance that you had nested views inside your constraintLayout? Because for a lot of full-time developers that I know and work with constraintLayout solved almost every need they had. so I would like to hear more from you on your problem.

Comment: I actually replaced 1 ConstraintLayout with a vertical LinearLayout that contained 3 ConstraintLayouts, and greatly improved scrolling speed. It was probably a question of the right constraints, and less interdependency.

Comment: I really think that you just had some wrong constraining, don't give up on that layout because I truly believe that it is a great layout. For me, it saves tons of layout making time and allowing me to allocate more time to writing code.